# Aurelia: sending fetch request to different port

Tags: aurelia

I have a PHP backend at port 7000. I use the webpack skeleton. How can I configure my fetch client to send requests to a different port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting `.withBaseUrl('api/')` you can just specify a port like `url:8000/api` and that should work from my experience, there may be a better way but that has worked for me in the past.

Or if you aren't specifying a base url the following should also work:

```
httpClient.fetch('http://localhost:7000/api/getsomedata')
    .then(response => return response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: I apologize for such a late reply. I tried the above but got an error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Hi, this is because your Web API is not configured for CORS so will only allow requests from the same address (including port). Depending on what platform you built your api with it will be different on how to allow cross origin requests.

Comment: Tnx. Will try to tweak my API. Also, didn't know that same origin included port.